# Black screen (onboard graphics) after uninstalling Nvidia drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I had taken out my graphics card and internal vga was enabled from BIOS. My pc ws running just fine on internal vga. So I decided to uninstall the Nvidia drivers as I wont be plugging in my graphics card again...

Now after the windows boot screen, my monitor goes black (yeah, BLACK screen, not power saving mode).  Safe mode still works.

In Device manager (in safe mode), theres a "Mirage driver" and a "SiS Mirage Graphics" under Display and drivers.

Do you know what might be going on? Any remedies?

Comment: You seem to know your way round a Windows-7 PC so I'll forego the obligatory "Are you sure it's plugged in?" and "Did you try restarting it?" preface. That said, y'all know what comes next: have you updated your drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Two display drivers in device manager was a hint. Anyways, I uninstalled both of them in device manager, rebooted, and updated the "Generic Display". Now theres only one "SiS Mirage Graphics".